# why does ls -Z returns files names with question marks next to them?

Tags: command-line, ls, syntax

why does `ls -Z` returns files names with question marks next to them? And what does this command do?

Comment: -1 for [a continued inability to read manpages](http://askubuntu.com/q/685620/158442).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) for `ls` says:

```
-Z, --context
       print any SELinux security context of each file
```

since you are not running `SELinux` the `?` appears in front of the file as it cannot read that part of it since it does not exist.

More information about `SELinux` can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer feels misleading. One can imply that `?` is displayed whenever `/etc/selinux/config` `SELINUX` is set to `disabled`.

I have it set to disabled, but running `ls -Z` shows `?` for some files while for others does return their security contexts. It is true that `?` will be displayed when selinux is not installed/in use, but it is not the complete answer.

[This](http://www.dark-hamster.com/operating-system/using-selinux-security-context-labeling/) article says `?` means the absence of a security label for that file/object.

To add one, use [chchon](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) command.